# What are the intermolecular forces between the following compounds in a mixture?

Tags: solutions, intermolecular-forces

I need to figure out the intermolecular force between the following compounds in a mixture:

- acetone-aniline,
- acetone-chloroform,
- ethanol-acetic acid,
- acetone-ethanol,
- ethanol-water

Can someone please share the type of 'intermolecular' bonding between these compounds and the diagrammatic representation as well?

[image: Acetone-Ethanol]
[image: Methanol-Acetic Acid]
[image: Acetone-Aniline]
[image: Ethanol-Distilled Water]
[image: Acetone-Chloroform]

These images are ignoring the bond angles. Do this look right? What about interactions other then hydrogen bonds and dipole-dipole interactions?

Comment: Become familiar with the different types of intermolecular forces (H-bonding, van der waals, etc...). Look at and maybe draw each structure of the listed molecules. Identify the functional groups and try and reason your way to some answer. Then come back and post what you have.

Comment: @dval98 I already know those concepts, I am just not sure how these would work for the specified chemical compounds. I have questions such as, where 'dimers' form and would I only show hydrogen bonding or other dipole-dipole interactions as well, will there be other dipole-dipole interactions, etc. Anyway, I have added my attempt to the question by making edits, please take a look at that, and give me some feedback, thank you.

Comment: Well, ignoring bond angles, the pictures are right, so what do you wanna know? Other interactions? Well, I imagine there's some halogen bonding between acetone and chloroform, for example.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force

Comment: You can do much beyond that. Specialists are still studying how H+ is solvated in water based solutions, just to give you an example of the complexity of the subject.